# How to send data from Modal, Form using react and bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

I am working with React to `POST` data in my local database. When I use just the `<form>`, it works fine. But whenever I am trying to use Modal and Bootstrap, it is giving me an error. I understand that my `handleChange/handleSubmit` is probably not assigning the values. Just wondering how to send the data from `Modal` to the `handleChange`.

Here is my code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      institutionName: {},
      institutionAddress: {},
      institutionPhone: {},
      allData: [],
    };
    this.onSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
// this will look at the API and save the incoming data in allData variable
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("/manageInstitution")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => this.setState({ allData: data }))
      .then(console.log(this.state.allData));
  }

// this is when submit button is pressed and data will be sent to database using api
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const data = {
      institutionName: this.state.institutionName,
      institutionAddress: this.state.institutionAddress,
      institutionPhone: this.state.institutionPhone,
    };

    fetch("/manageInstitution", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .catch((error) => console.error("Error: ", error))
      .then((response) => console.log("Success: ", response));

    window.location.reload(false);
  }

// when a field changes in the form, do assignment to the state
  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value.trim(),
    });
  };

  handleModalShowHide() {
    this.setState({ showHide: !this.state.showHide });
  }

  render() {
    const { allData } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="body">
        <h4>Super Admin View</h4>

        <div>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => this.handleModalShowHide()}>
            Add New Institution
          </Button>

          <Modal
            aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
            show={this.state.showHide}
            onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
          >
            <Modal.Header
              closeButton
              onClick={() => this.handleModalShowHide()}
            >
              <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
                <h5>Add New Institution</h5>
              </Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
              <Form className="col-lg-6 offset-lg-3">
                <Form.Group className="mb-3">
                  <Form.Label htmlFor="institutionName">
                    Institution Name:
                  </Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control
                    type="text"
                    size="sm"
                    name="institutionName"
                    placeholder="Enter Institution Name"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    required
                  />
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group className="mb-3">
                  <Form.Label htmlFor="institutionAddress">
                    Institution Address:
                  </Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control
                    type="text"
                    size="sm"
                    name="institutionAddress"
                    placeholder="Enter Institution Address"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    required
                  />
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group className="mb-3">
                  <Form.Label htmlFor="institutionPhone">
                    Institution Phone:
                  </Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control
                    type="tel"
                    size="sm"
                    name="institutionPhone"
                    placeholder="i.e 01911223344"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    pattern="[0-9]{3}"
                    required
                  />
                </Form.Group>
              </Form>
              <Modal.Footer>
                <Button
                  variant="secondary"
                  onClick={() => this.handleModalShowHide()} >Close </Button>
                {"  "}
                <Button
                  className="btn btn-primary"
                  type="submit"
                  onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</Button>
              </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal.Body>
          </Modal>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default addNewInstitution;
```

Here is the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')
handleSubmit
D:/eduBD-React/eduBD/client/src/components/superadmin/manageInstitution.jsx:30
  27 |    event.preventDefault();
  28 | 
  29 |    const data = {
> 30 |      institutionName: this.state.institutionName,
  31 |      institutionAddress: this.state.institutionAddress,
  32 |      institutionPhone: this.state.institutionPhone,
  33 |    };
```

Answer (score 0):

> You need to bind or use an Arrow function to have `this` to point to
> correct reference [refer docs here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: "hello"
  };

  handleChangeWithArrow = () => { // use this way to avoid such errors
    console.log(this.state.name);

    this.setState({ name: "helloo Im changed" });
  };
  handleChange() {
    // need to bind this to work or use an arrow function
    console.log(this.state.name);

    this.setState({ name: "helloo Im changed" });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleChange}>Error Produced on Click</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleChangeWithArrow}>
          Click Me to change Name
        </button>
        {this.state.name}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.querySelector('#root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I am hitting the API but it's showing `handleChange` is sending NULL to my DB quary?

Comment: @ArifHossain That's what I'm trying to convey you with the above answer.... the error u mentioned clearly shows that when reading state fro this.state it is referred as this-> which is undefined > undefined.state and so is the error, to make it work convert your `handleSubmit` to an arrow function

Comment: I have converted `handleSubmit` to arrow function but same error.

Comment: try to attach a code sandbox link ... would be easy to check

Comment: Were able to solve it. Had a miss-spelled variable name in one of the files. Thanks a lot though for your suggestion about the arrow functions.

Comment: its quite common.... glad it helped you :)